# Reference (not copy) a subrange of a one-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays

Suppose I have the following method signature

```
int f (int[] values)
```

and I call it like this:

```
int[] myValues = {1,2,3,4,5}
f (myvalues)
```

then, since arrays are objects, and objects are reference types, f receives a *reference* to the ints, and can change their value so the caller can see the changes.

**Now how can I then call `f` in a way that it receives a reference to the array elements 2,3,4 (i.e. subrange from index 1 to 3 inclusive) without copying `myValues`?**
Something like

```
f ((int[]) myvalues[1])
```

which of course does not compile (and would leave open which size the array would have) but might transport the idea I am looking for?

In other languages, I could use pointer arithmetics to calculate the address of `myValues[2]`, and treat it a the beginning of an array of integer, and pass an explicit count parameter. (Quite type-unsafe, of course.)

**Can I do this in Java without copying the three elements' values to an intermediate array?**

Sub-question: Are the array elements, being value types, stored at consecutive addresses at all, or is the array composed of elements that are references to integers? Could it be the question does not make sense because even if the answer to the latter was "yes", I could not build on that since that would be an implementation detail that a Java source must not build upon it? It even cannot -- there is no semantics for it, right?

*Edit: Stupid index error*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return a range/subset of items in arrays (also Collection) without creating a new instance of the container.

I cannot answer the second without guessing, but **IF** the JVM wants to allocate 2 regions of memory for one array, it can do it without you knowing.

Comment: >>IF the JVM wants to allocate 2 regions of memory for one array, it can do it without you knowing<< OK then it is not one region, and I cannot reference it without copying. Doh. Thanks.

Comment: Too bad. Delphi can do this (but not in a type-safe way).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `List` instead of an array.

```
int[] myValues = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
List<Integer> myValuesList = Arrays.asList(myValues);

// change the argument of function to List
doSomething(List<Integer> input);

// and then just give the function a range of the myValues.
// This List is still backed by your array myValues, it just
// a view of the original array.
doSomething(myValuesList.subList(2,3));
```

Comment: the `myValues` is an array of primitive type values or objects?

Comment: array of int, i.e. elements are of primitive type

Comment: I think creating another array which contains the values that you want to pass to the f() is the appropriate way here. Since the values are `int`, not object, so you they are not *reference*. Are you concerned of performance, memory or something?

Comment: 1. I have existing code I don't wanna touch, and that supplies an array of ints. I need to pass a subrange of such an array to other existing methods accepting an array of ints. I just don't want to touch that existing code. 2. If in some method I receive the array param and copy a subrange of it into a new array and pass that to some other method, upon return, I will need to copy the changes back into the caller´s array, which would not be required if the changes made by the lowerlevel method would "write-throw" to original array.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++ this would be terribly easy to do with a bit of pointer arithmetic, but in Java, I am not so sure it is possible.

The best you could do is use the [copyOfRange](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) method although that makes a **deep copy**.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I don't want a copy, but a subrange reference.